# Equivariant homology of Hilb and torus stable curves

Tags: hilbert-schemes, homology, combinatorial-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

The torus equivariant homology of a compact homogeneous variety $G/B$ may be described by using the "skeleton" consisting of torus fixed points and the torus invariant curves that connect them.  Combinatorially, this produces a copy of the Hasse diagram of Bruhat order inside $G/B$, with edges labeled by appropriate roots.  The torus invariant curves can be given explicitly as the images of certain $SL_2$'s inside $G/B$.  Is there a similarly explicit construction of the torus invariant curves inside the Hilbert scheme of $n$ points in $\mathbb{C}^2$?  If so, does one obtain the same description of equivariant homology via localization (with dominance order replacing Bruhat order)?

Edit: Thanks to David Speyer for the explicit construction of a torus invariant curve here: [Reference for combinatorics of cell decomposition of the Hilbert scheme of points in the plane](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52807/reference-for-combinatorics-of-cell-decomposition-of-the-hilbert-scheme-of-points/52865#52865)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work as simply as it does for $G/B$, because there aren't finitely many $T$-invariant curves.  Instead they will come in families whose unions are things like products of projective spaces.  Although there will be a larger torus acting on each such family which has finitely many $T$-invariant curves, it won't extend to an action on the whole variety.

If you can work out the $T$-equivariant cohomology of the components of the fixed point sets for all codimension $1$ subtori of $T$, then you can take the intersection of all those things inside $H_T(X^T)$ just as you would if there were finitely many $T$-invariant curves.  This has been worked out for $Hilb_n(C^2)$, and more generally the Hilbert scheme of a smooth toric surface, in Evain, "The Chow ring of punctual Hilbert schemes of toric surfaces".

Comment: Well, it's nice to know that one can compute equivariant Chow of Hilb so explicitly using this method.  Thank you!